# Servlet: should I wrap all exceptions in ServletException?

Tags: java, servlets

Suppose I have a servlet that does all necessary processing in a method defined like this:

```
protected abstract void process(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response);
```

What is the correct way to implement *Servlet* interface?

Wrap runtime exceptions in *ServletException*:

```
protected void service(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  try {
    process(request, response);
  } catch(Throwable t){
    throw new ServletException(t);
  }
}
```

or throw runtime exceptions as is:

```
protected void service(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  process(request, response);
}
```

Comment: wrapper is no more required..

Comment: It has never been. You can throw any runtime exception from any method.

Comment: I know you CAN throw runtime exception from servlet. My question is SHOULD you?

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your code only if you have to handle the exception, otherwise, wrap is not required.